# Some Tailwind classes are working, the others are not

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I try to use some tailwind classes, but there's classes that not working properly.

`<h2 class="text-6xl">Test</h2>`   Is working

`<h2 class="text-4xl">Test</h2>`   Isn't working

`<h2 class="text-orange-500">Test</h2>`   Is working

`<h2 class="mt-4">Test</h2>`   Isn't working

Answer (score 1):

Ah, i have to --watch my tailwind before.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to watch by running

> npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch